# creating an Itemview inside a CompositeView with Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to build an app where there is a `CompositeView` that handles mouse events, allowing you to draw rectangles inside it(the CompositeView is a collection of rectangles). I'm calculating/storing all the needed data for a rectangle (basically width, height, top, left and border css properties) inside the `CompositeView`.

Since I'm calculating stuff, I've used the `itemViewOptions` function, that returns an object with all data necessary, that will be passed as options to my `ItemView` (RectangleView).

In the `initialize` method of the `ItemView` I call the setCssStyle method, that applies the css properties to the view.

Here's my CompositeView (ScreenView) and ItemView (RectangleView) code (calculations and data-stopring methods ommited for brevity)

```
var RectangleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "<div>I am a rectangle</div>",
  className: "rectangle",

  initialize: function(options){
    this.left = options.left;
    this.top = options.top;
    this.width = options.width;
    this.height = options.height;
    this.border = options.border;
    this.setCssStyle();
  },
  setCssStyle: function () {
    this.$el.css({
      'width': this.width + 'px',
      'height': this.height + 'px',
      'top': this.top + 'px',
      'left': this.left + 'px',
      'border': this.border
    });
  }
});


var ScreenView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: "<div>  </div>",
  className:"screen",
  itemView: RectangleView,

  itemViewOptions: function() {
    return {
      left: this.left,
      top: this.top,
      width: this.width,
      height: this.height,
      border: this.border
    }
  },

[...]

});
```

I've read that I need to override the `buildItemView` method passing it 3 parameters: `item, ItemViewType, itemViewOptions` according to the [Marionette Documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-builditemview)

Th problem is that I'm a bit confused and I don't really know what is the `item` parameter I'm supposed to pass. Is it the model for the ItemView? I tried different stuff and kept getting errors, so chances are I'm missing something fundamental here.

Also, currently I don't have a model for my RectangleView. Should I create one, and how can I pass the `itemViewOptions` from my `CompositeView` to my `ItemView` and eventually to the model?

I apologize in advance if I didn't explain my issue well, but my brain feels kinda mushy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to figure this out on my own, I guess I needed some slep to clear my head! I don't know if it's an optimal solution, but it works for me.

First of all, I've switched from a `CompositeView` to a `CollectionView` since I don't need recursiveness. I've also created an empty `Rectangle`model and a `Rectangles` collection.

In my App.Initializer when I show the CollectionView I also pass the rectangles collection to it! `.show(new ScreenView({collection: rectangles}));`

Now, as you might remember, the whole deal was being able to draw rectangles inside the CollectionView, the rectangles drawn within the CollectionView would be added in a collection (each would have a model etc etc...)

The ideal place to put that code was on my `mouseup` event inside my CollectionView (think about it, you click--> drag-->release the mouse button to draw a box)

```
[...]
  handleMouseUp: function(e) {
    [...]
    if (this.dragging===1) {

      //passing the itemViewOptions on a helper
      var modelHelper = this.itemViewOptions();

      //instantiating Rectangle by passing it the itemViewOptions
      var rectangle = new Rectangle (modelHelper);

      //adding newly instantiated rectangle in the collection
      this.collection.add(rectangle);
      console.log(this.collection);
    }
  },
```

As soon as you add the rectangle in the collection, the CollectionView will take care of rendering it! :)

Please let me know if there could be any optimizations or other ways of  doing this! Now I have to take care of the css properties because my rectangles won't render in place :/